# PHP's phar extension is missing. magento2.4.5

Tags: magento2, php, composer, bug

I have been installing Magento2.4.5 getting below error while executing **composer install** Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

> PHP's phar extension is missing. Composer requires it to run. Enable
> the extension or recompile php without --disable-phar then try again.

I was installed all the require tools based on this but no luck. Pleas advise
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-php-8-1-and-set-up-a-local-development-environment-on-ubuntu-22-04